# Problems installing pySpeex

Tags: python, wrapper, speex

When I try to install the pySpeex wrapper on a raspberry Pi, I've got the following error message:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop/speex-1.2rc2 $ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'speex' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict- prototypes -fPIC -I../libspeex -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c speex.c -o     build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/speex.o -g
speex.c:10:19: fatal error: speex.h: No such file or directory
```

I do have both speex.c and also speex.h in the same directory. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should create another directory in `~/Desktop/speex-*` and call it, for example, `build`.

```
mkdir -p build && cd build
python ../setup.py install
```

The compiler command tries to use the `../libspeex` directory for headers, but it should be `~Desktop/libspeex` then which's not likely to exist, so you can try to move this directory there or make a symlink to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! success!